# How to contact Grails web maintainers?

Tags: grails, web

This probably isn't the best place to post this question. I can't find any way of contacting the Grails.org web site maintainers. I've looked all over the web site and in "Community" but can't find what looks like the right thing. Can someone point me in the right directions please?

My problem is that the presentation for 1) What is Grails on https://grails.org/learn just results in an empty pop-up box. This happens on both Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there are many ways online u can learn grails ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues for the website can be filed at http://jira.grails.org/browse/WEBSITE

Comment: Thank you. I posted [there](https://jira.grails.org/browse/WEBSITE-282?jql=project%20%3D%20WEBSITE). It seems to be an HTTP/HTTPS problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is a flash presentation and the url you have opened uses SSL (secured channel) as a result it tries to block the flash content as unauthorized script.

In Chrome, make sure you load the script as an unsafe script (from the address bar) and you should be able to see the presentation. Same would be applicable for Firefox.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work. The link in the anchor is href="#modal-pres1" (-> https://grails.org/learn#modal-pres1). I tried loading that from the address bar in Chrome and I just get the Getting Started, Learn Grails page again.

Comment: It did work for me and I hope it would have worked for others. Please follow Greame's answer if you still see a problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll lodge a query as @Graeme suggests.

Comment: On a closer look I see you mentioned about the link to the modal window, but I was pointing at the main URL `https://grails.org/learn`. If possible please read my answer carefully again. I am sure it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. So the steps that worked for me in Chrome were:  
1. Open https://grails.org/learn  
2. Spot the shield icon in the address bar (as per your answer and click on it.  
4. Select the 'Load unsafe script' option  
5. View the presentation!  

I've never spotted that icon before so misunderstood your asnwer to mean use http: as part of the address. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it was helpful and was able to answer according to the context of the question. :)